# How to get the number of unprocessed messages in a Redis queue in Symfony

Tags: symfony, redis, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I use Redis transport based on streams. How to get the number of unprocessed messages in a Redis queue in Symfony 4? I can get pending messages with XPENDING^ but how get unprocessed?

Comment: Im also researching since days about getting any clue on to get some kind of stats out of the queue. Would be very useful when i could get somehow info on how many messages are currently in queue being processed/pending for processing.  Would think of this as the 2nd basic feature to expect on a queue - for my understanding as a newbie at least.

Comment: Posted a related question, but from a Redis perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66010304/how-to-count-unread-or-acknowledged-messages-in-a-redis-stream

Answer (score 0):

In the redis-cli enter : `XPENDING messages symfony`

Comment: This only returns the number of messages that have been fetched/read by a worker, but not yet acknowledged. Under normal circumstances, a queue will contain lots of messages that have not yet been fetched.