# How to count unread or acknowledged messages in a Redis stream?

Tags: redis

Using Redis 5.0.3, let's say we create a stream called `streamy` and a consumer group `consumers`:

```
XGROUP CREATE streamy consumers $ MKSTREAM
```

Then add a few messages to it:

```
XADD streamy * message "The beginning"
XADD streamy * message "The middle"
XADD streamy * message "The end"
```

And finally read and acknowledge the first one:

```
XREADGROUP GROUP consumers consumer1 COUNT 1 STREAMS streamy >
XACK streamy consumers 1612270017551-0
```

I know I can use `XLEN streamy` to get the total number of messages (3), and `XINFO CONSUMERS streamy consumers` to get the number of pending messages for each consumer (0).
But how can I find the number of unread messages (2), or the number of acknowledged messages (1), whichever is easiest to find?

Also, given a specific message ID, is there any way to check if that message has been read and/or acknowledged?

Comment: Possible answers at: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8392